# IList or IQueryable OrderBy method which accepts a string parameter as selector?

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, sorting, gridview

This [*asp.net entity framework tutorial*](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/continuing-with-ef/using-the-entity-framework-and-the-objectdatasource-control-part-3-sorting-and-filtering) describes how you can use ObjectDataSource with your BLL and provide a method which includes a sort expression for use with a GridView.

```
public IEnumerable<Department> GetDepartments(string sortExpression)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortExpression))
    {
        sortExpression = "Name";
    }         
    return context.Departments.Include("Person").OrderBy("it." + sortExpression).ToList();
}
```

The problem is, it uses the **string** sortExpression from the ObjectDataSource in the OrderBy() method.  I can't find a reference to this method anywhere.  Does it exist and if not, what is the best way to allow sorting of a GridView with a custom BLL.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358828.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic Linq supports OrderBy with a string as the argument: http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/